# VSCode semantic highlighting not working after installing Extension Pack for Java. How can I restore it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added the Extension Pack for Java to vscode, and after doing so, all semantic highlighting across all languages broke. Note that highlighting not dependent on semantics, such as reserved words and rainbow curly braces was not effected.

I tried to fix this by changing `editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled` from `configuredByTheme` to `true`, but this did nothing. I also tried uninstalling the Extension Pack for Java, and this also did nothing. I also un- and re-installed vscode to no effect.

My operating system is Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: 1) what if you uninstall and reinstall again? does it still happen? 2) anything in the output logs that looks related? (View > Output)